# Phaser framework on the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, phaser-framework

Can not the phaser work on the server side of the nodejs. And if it is allowed and can work, is this a bad idea?

```
C:\Users\user\tanks-game\node_modules\phaser-ce\build\phaser.js:21762
PIXI: PIXI || {},
      ^
ReferenceError: PIXI is not defined
```

Comment: What do you want to obtain? How your code/package is? How you installed Phaser on the server?

Comment: npm install --save phaser-ce@2.9.1

Comment: Since I'm trying to create a multiplayer game in
 Real-time, I need the server to work with the physics of the game.

Comment: Then I just tried to connect the module:
var phaser = require ('phaser-ce')
And as a result, the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible, unless running in PhantomJS or something similar. Phaser is heavily reliant on the DOM, which doesn’t exist in a Node.js environment.

Use a third-party library to compute physics, or roll your own.

Using the entire Phaser framework on your server would use up a lot of memory regardless, and your computations would likely be slower since they were based on a browser instance, rather than computed on-the-fly.